# Is the arithmetic-geometric mean of 1 and 2 rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, irrational-numbers

It is easy to show that, for two fixed real numbers $\alpha, \beta > 0$, the sequences given by $a_ 1 = \frac{\alpha + \beta }{2}$, $ g_1 = \sqrt{\alpha\beta}$, and $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + g_n}{2}$, $g_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_ng_n}$ are both convergent and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n$. Let's call this limit $\operatorname{agm}(\alpha, \beta)$. I am convinced that the number $\operatorname{agm}(1,2)$ is irrational, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What is $b_n$ in $a_{n + 1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}2$?  Should it be $g_n$?

Comment: It boils down to understand if some complete elliptic integral of the first kind is irrational.  In fact, $$\operatorname{agm}(1, \, 2)=\frac{\pi}{4} \cdot 3 K\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-1}.$$

Numerical computations seem to suggest so.

Comment: I agree with Francisco.  It would be truly remarkable if
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} \cdot 3 K\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-1}\qquad\text{is rational}
\tag1$$
Note $K(1/3) = K(-1/3)$.  And $(1)$ holds if and only if $K(1/3)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: For some $k$ called singular values, the complete elliptic integral $K(k)$ can be expressed using $\pi$ and the $\Gamma$ function at rational arguments. These $k$ are algebraic numbers but the following table does not include any rational $k$: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html

Comment: Perhaps studying the symmetries of the considered elliptic integral could help determine the structure of $\mathbb{Q}(K(1/p))$ for $p$ a prime number.

Comment: A [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1661858) was asked at math.SE but unfortunately does not contain much information.